# If in php file create a file in js, it is save only when execution of php is end?

Tags: php, runtime

If i have a long php file with many loop and inside the code i create an empty `javascript` file:

```
  //EXAMPLE
  $path= 'folder/file.js';
  $content= 'var example= "text";';
  file_put_contents($path, $content);
```

This file is created only when execution of php file is end ?

I'm writing with phone and i can test it (really i don't know how can possible to test this thing). 
I hope you don't donwvote me. Thanks a lot and sorry for my english...

Comment: No, it will create in during execution of the script. Not at the end of the script.

Comment: Luckily ... in my php, after creating the js file, I include the huge external files. That's why the execution is terminated after a long time.

Comment: @KodosJohnson and if for some reason the excetution php stops (but after i have create the file js) the file it will create in its folder ?

Comment: Yes, it will still be created.